# Model first of EF, how to define navigation property relationship without setting foreign key between tables in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to create following two tables,

1. **Driver** table with following columns(DriverId,DeptId,Version,CarNo, License)
   **DriverId** is primary key, **DeptId,Version,CarNo** forms unique keys.

   - DeptId will have duplicate values in this table
2. and I want to create **DriverTrips** table with (DeptId, TotalIncome) column. My question is in Entity Framework how can I make use of navigation properties, if there is no foreign key relationship ?Is that possible? Basically, I don't want to repeat DeptId values in this table.

I looked at many other posts did not get any answer. Any help to guide me in a right direction is appreciated.

Comment: can you post the code where you have implemented so far ?

Comment: @Sampath Since we use model first. I'm still designing my schema. So before I move forward to code I wanted to make sure if navigational properties work without foreign key between tables. Let me know If im missing anything?

Comment: If you are designing the schema, why would you avoid FK relationships that are the foundation of a relational database? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @SteveGreene Basically, our business people do not want duplicate rows in DriverTrips table, for each DeptId there should be only one row.   If I create a foreign key relationship based on the primary key from driver table, I will have to create one more column DriverId in DriverTrips table and they do not want that. So I just wanted to make sure if we can use navigational properties when there is no relationship.? Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Sounds like you might need a junction table. Assuming your entities are Driver, Trips and then DriverTrips that's a pretty standard many-to-many design.

Comment: @SteveGreene Yes I thought of it but they do not want any relationship or extra table. So can we use navigational properties with just two tables?

Comment: No, EF requires FK for navigation. You could hack something like this: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2012/02/01/Making-Do-with-Absent-Foreign-Keys.aspx

Comment: @SteveGreene Ok, I will take a look. By looking at the link it seems it is for code first approach.

Comment: If you want to aggregate multiple records from your Driver table into the DriverTrips table there are not many EF alternatives. You could create an aggregate view or trigger on the DB side I suppose.

Comment: @SteveGreene Thank you. I will look into it